# How to create a customer scorer when doing cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I try:

```
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, features, target, cv=percent 
                                             , scoring =     \
metrics.make_scorer(metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support) )
    print(scores)
```

I receive an error:

> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py",
> line 1537, in _score
> % (str(score), type(score))) ValueError: scoring must return a number, got (array([ 0.375     ,  0.91290323]), array([ 0.25      ,
> 0.94966443]), array([ 0.3       ,  0.93092105]), array([ 36, 298], dtype=int64)) (<class 'tuple'>) instead.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your scoring function `precision_recall_fscore_support` is returning four arrays of numbers (precision, recall, fbeta_score and support) but `scoring` requires the callable returns only a number.

Try using only the `fbeta_score`:

```
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(
    clf, features, target, cv=percent,
    scoring=metrics.make_scorer(
        metrics.fbeta_score))
```